# Showing that estimator is minimax

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

I have the following question. Let $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ and consider estimating $p\in(0,1)$ with loss function,
$$
L(p,\hat{p})=\left(1-\frac{\hat{p}}{p}\right)^2.
$$
I need to show that the estimator $\hat{p}=0$ is minimax.

I have an idea on how to do this since I have a theorem that says that if an estimator is admissible and has constant risk then it is minimax. Constant risk is easy to check is this case,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[L(p,0)\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(1-\frac{0}{p}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[1\right]\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

I am having a harder time showing that $\hat{p}=0$ is admissible. My idea is to assume that it is not admissible; then there exists an estimator $\tilde{p}$ with the property,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[L(p,\tilde{p})\right] \leq 1
$$
for all $p$ and with strict inequality for at least one $p\in(0,1)$. The left-hand side can be expanded,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[L(p,\tilde{p})\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\tilde p^2}{p^2} - 2\frac{\tilde p}{p} + 1\right] \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p^2\right]}{p^2} - 2\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p\right]}{p} + 1.
\end{align}
Combining this with the definition of inadmissibility above we have,
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p^2\right]}{p^2} \leq 2\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p\right]}{p},
$$
which can be written,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p^2\right] \leq 2p\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p\right].
$$

Unfortunately this is as far as I can get without some further guidance. Can someone point me in the right direction? I haven't used the fact that $X$ is Binomial...

Comment: This is an exercise from Wasserman's book right?

Comment: Yes, but Wasserman's question also asks the reader to prove that the estimator is unique in addition to being minimax. The question is apparently based on this paper https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176346248 but it is too advanced for me to read.

Comment: I must say Wasserman has great exercises. Fun question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\E{\mathbb{E}}$From your last expression, Jensen's inequality tells us that for an estimator to have risk uniformly less than one
$$\E[\tilde p]^2 \leq \E[\tilde p^2] \leq 2p\E[\tilde p]$$
so $\E[\tilde p]$ satisfies $x(x-2p) \leq x^2 - 2px \leq 0$ or equivalently  $\E[\tilde p]\in[0,2p]$. But since $p$ is could be arbitrarily close to zero this implies $\E[\tilde p]=0$ is necessary for any estimator to have risk uniformly at most one for all $p$.

Plugging this back into the risk expansion we have
$$E[L(p,\tilde p)] = 1 + \frac{\E[\tilde p^2]}{p^2}\geq 1$$ so the only estimator which could possibly have risk uniformly less than one must have $\E[\tilde p^2] = 0$ or $\tilde p = 0$ almost surely. $\blacksquare$

Comment: After this solution was posted, I thought of an alternative approach as follows. After we see that $\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p\right] = 0$, we can use the completeness of $X$ ($X$ is a complete statistic for a Binomial distribution) to say that if $\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde p(X)\right] = 0$ then we must have that $\text{Pr}\left[\tilde p(X) = 0\right] = 1$.

Comment: @user3064222 how do we know the estimator is complete?

Comment: The sample $X$ is complete so any function $g(X)$ with expectation zero must equal zero with probability one. There is a proof for the Binomial distribution on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)